# What is the most optimized way to implement an ignore case dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, optimization, refactoring, iequalitycomparer

Imagine we have a custom dictionary class which is derived from `Dictionary<string, object>`. Dictionary is ***case-insensitive*** about keys and elements arrange is not important.
So what is the most optimized way to compare two instance of this class, or in another word what is the best override of
 `Equals` method in this class.

I tried to use these two ways to implement this class. But i'm not sure which way is better than the other.
Please help me to choose the best way or correct me if i made any mistake.

*First implementation:*

```
public class CustomeDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public CustomeDictionary() :
     base(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
    }

    public CustomeDictionary(CustomeDictionary CustomeDictionary) :
     base(CustomeDictionary, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomeDictionary other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        if (Count != other.Count)
            return false;

        foreach (var (key, value) in this)
            if (!other.ContainsKey(key) || !value.Equals(other[key]))
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as CustomeDictionary);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Sum(i => (i.Key.ToLower(), i.Value).GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

*The second way* was to use another class which is an implementation of 
`IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` which can help to use some efficient Linq methods like 
`Except` to override the `Equals` and overload `==`.

The EqualityComparer CustomClass

```
public class CustomKeyValuePair : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, object> x, KeyValuePair<string, object> y)
        => GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);


    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, object> obj)
    {
        var (key, value) = obj;
        return (key.ToLower(), value).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and I have used it like below in Equals:

```
   public bool Equals(CustomHashTable other)
   {
      return this.Except(other, new CustomKeyValuePair()).Any();
   }
```

Please help me to improve and refactor the code.

Comment: `GetHashCode` should only be used to rule out equality, not to determine it.

Comment: Constructs like `if (!other.ContainsKey(key) || !value.Equals(other[key]))` drive me nutty. Use `TryGetValue` instead. Less duplicity and "more efficient" fsvo. `if (other.TryGetValue(key, out var otherValue) && object.Equals(value, otherValue))`. The inverse expression (see De Morgan's Law) is also easier to read here, IMOHO. In general cases, I often use `object.Equals(a,b)` as it implicitly guards against null values, which might not be expected even though they are not "banned" at the insert sites.

Comment: If you're just looking for a code review, you should probably post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This will also fail if the value is `null` (even if the other value is also `null`): `!value.Equals(other[key])`

Comment: You should avoid `Dictionary<string, object>`. Generics exist so we do **not** have to use object for those types anymore. It throws out all compile time typesaftey. There has to be a concerete interface or abstract class you can nail it down to. | Internally, Dictionaries are also HashTables. They use HashCode comparision to exclude equality of keys quickly.

Comment: @RufusL when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". For example, the title should describe what the code does instead of CR goals... See also [this meta answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @Christopher Actually I have to use object as valus because am using it to implement a logic that need some keyValuePair which value type is not explicit. and there are a few steps to guess the type.

Comment: @RufusL You mean it is not to use == with getHashCode(), So if I Override the GetHashCode then implictly will used in Equals() ? somthing like
```x.Equals(y);``` not to use ```x.GetHashCode()==y.GetHashCode()```

Comment: @M.H.Ahmadi The point being made is that equal hash codes means two objects *might* be equal, and unequal hash codes means they *definitely aren't* equal. That is all the hash code tells you. Thus `public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, object> x, KeyValuePair<string, object> y)
        => GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);` is wrong - since it is relying on `GetHashCode` doing something it doesn't promise to do. _`HashCode` is like your last name. If someone has a last name that isn't Wills then you know they aren't me. But having last name of Wills doesn't mean they are me._

Comment: @RufusL 
```if (!other.ContainsKey(key) || !(value?.Equals(other[key])??false))``` is that correct?

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you so much good point

Comment: I don't think so - `value?.Equals(other[key]) ?? false` will be false if `value` is `null`, regardless of the other value. what if the other value is also `null`? Maybe something like: `value?.Equals(other[key]) ?? other[key] == null`

Comment: Thank you so much @RufusL, It was so helpful.